# dataframe grouped by two elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

For example, there is a DataFrame named df. And I group it by column 'A' and column 'B',then get the mean value of column 'C'.
I use the following code:

```
df = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].mean()
df = df.to_frame()
```

But finally I want to get a new DataFrame with 3 columns('A','B','C').How can I do after these code?

Comment: Either `df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['C'].mean()`  or `df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].mean().reset_index()`.

Comment: @ayhan.yes,it worked.Thx.

Comment: df.groupy(['A','B']).agg({'C':'mean'})